# Knockout observableArray object empty when pushing an object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a ViewModel that is structured like this:

```
function CallLogViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // Observables
        self.client = {
            Id: ko.observable(),
            Name: ko.observable().extend({required: true, message: 'Name is required'}),
            Surname: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, message: 'Surname is required' }),
            EmailAddress: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, message: 'Email is required', email: true }),
            Mobile: ko.observable(),
            Fax: ko.observable(),
            Tel: ko.observable(),
            Area: ko.observable(),
            HasCar: ko.observable(),
            HeardAboutMethodId: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, message: 'Please select option' }),
            DateOfBirth: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, message: 'DateOfBirth is required' }),
            Comments: ko.observableArray(),
            Calls: ko.observableArray()
        };


        self.comment = {
            Id: ko.observable(),
            Value: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, message: 'Comment is required' }),
            ClientId: ko.observable(),
            Created: ko.observable()
        };


        self.addComment = function () {
            self.comment.Created = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss');
            self.client.Comments.push(self.comment);

            self.comment.Created = '';
            self.comment.Value = '';

            $('#ClientCommentsTable').DataTable();

            console.log(self.client.Comments());
        };


    };
```

When I add a new *self.comment* object into the array object it does display the comment in the table but the array object shows that the values are empty strings?

Does it have something to do with how I clear the comment object?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are doing. Can you add a working snippet? You can create one through the edit question menu using the code `<>` button.

Comment: I want to add a self.comment object to sel.client.Comments object but when i view the self.client.Comments object it shows the values as empty strings

Comment: I think the problem is with the fact that `self.comment` is not recreated everytime while it is pushed to `self.client.comments`. But I'd need a working example to confirm that.

Comment: `Created` and `Value` are observables. To set the value, you need to use `self.comment.Value('');` and `self.comment.Created(moment()....)`. Also, you need to create a new object using the properties of  `self.comment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.client.Comments.push({ Id: self.comment.Id, Value: self.comment.Value, ClientId: self.comment.ClientId, Created: moment()  });
```